# Creating a python script to login into a website and pull HTML data

Tags: python, html, curl, beautifulsoup

Hi I hope someone can help me,

I'm trying to create a script that logs into a website and pulls a value from the HTML I have installed BeautifulSoup and i've tried to use curl but I can't seem to login to the site. The HTML on the site uses j_username" and j_password

Thanks

Comment: I've built several crawlers with PyCurl + BeautifulSoup + Chrome Developer Console... that's all you need

Comment: Any specific errors using `PyCurl`? HTTP basic authentication or other?

Comment: does this website use the windows credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module. To retrieve HTML using basic authentication:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> html = r.text
```

Then use `bs4` to parse HTML for the specific content you need.